# Installing Xtext on IBM RSA 9.6.1

Tags: xtext, rational-rsa

I would like to install Xtext 2.11 (or more) on IBM RSA 9.6.1, but this does not work...

There is no error message during installation, but when trying to create a new Xtext project, the following error occurs:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.xtext.service.AbstractGenericModule
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:346)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:273)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:632)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:586)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:538)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:525)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:419)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:809)
at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui.internal.Activator.getSharedStateModule(Activator.java:90)
at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui.internal.Activator.createInjector(Activator.java:64)
at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui.internal.Activator.getInjector(Activator.java:55)
at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui.XtextExecutableExtensionFactory.getInjector(XtextExecutableExtensionFactory.java:24)
at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.guice.AbstractGuiceAwareExecutableExtensionFactory.create(AbstractGuiceAwareExecutableExtensionFactory.java:51)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:262)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:291)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:286)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardElement.createExecutableExtension(WorkbenchWizardElement.java:123)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardElement.createWizard(WorkbenchWizardElement.java:261)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.NewWizardNewPage$5.createWizard(NewWizardNewPage.java:737)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardNode$1$1.run(WorkbenchWizardNode.java:142)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardNode$1.run(WorkbenchWizardNode.java:124)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardNode.getWizard(WorkbenchWizardNode.java:120)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(WizardSelectionPage.java:107)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.java:98)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.NewWizardSelectionPage.advanceToNextPageOrFinish(NewWizardSelectionPage.java:71)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.NewWizardNewPage$1.doubleClick(NewWizardNewPage.java:361)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:833)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:830)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1470)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1264)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:252)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$0(OpenStrategy.java:249)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:311)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4418)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4236)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3824)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.NewProjectAction.run(NewProjectAction.java:115)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$$Lambda$47.00000000171FA7F0.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4418)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4236)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3824)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.xtext.service.AbstractGenericModule cannot be found by org.eclipse.xtext.ui.shared_2.11.0.v20170130-0818
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:809)
    ... 86 more

Is there any way to install a functional Xtext on IBM RSA 9.6.1 ?

Comment: there is no trial link for 9.6.1 only older ones

Comment: You're right! (I made an update after the 9.6 installation). But the problem is the same with the 9.6 version... So you can try this one...